# Using Event Cards to Move off Vine Walls

Tags: summoner-wars

When playing with a faction such as the Swamp Orcs who have vine walls, the rules state that units roll before moving off of vine walls to see if they take damage.

But do units still have to roll for damage when they are moved with an event card which says you can pick up a unit and "place" it elswhere? In other words, would an event that lets you pick up a unit and place it elsewhere on the board require a roll for damage when the unit is taken from a vine wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you do not have to roll for units that are removed from a Vine Wall if they do not move.** The word *move* is a keyword in Summoner Wars, and unless the ability or event specifically uses it, the movement would not be considered a *move*. Note that during the movement phase, units move.

[This thread](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/sum_forums/archive/index.php/t-1208.html) over on the Plaid Hat Games forums reiterates this: "Note that this only applies to 'moving'. Abilities that place a [card] somewhere are not affected by Vine Walls."